# Why element.addClass in directive doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Element

```
<button ud-listener="item.status">{{item.value}}</button>
```

and I have the following directive

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.$watch(attrs.myDirective, function(val)
            {
                if(!isUndefined(val))
                {
                    element.addClass(val);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        element.removeClass(val);
                    }, 2000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What am I trying to do is:

I am receiving json formated datas with socket-io and I am watching the myDirective which holds the value, which is required for add/-removeClass.

At the beginning it works like a charm, the directive adds the class to the element and removes it after 2 sec. without any problem. But few min later it does not add the class to all elements only to few of them.

Is there another way to do it? I only want to addClass to the element and removeClass after 2 seconds.

Comment: Might it because the value you are $watching in stops changing after a few minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's because either:

You're not referencing JQuery ... or...

Your JQuery reference doesn't come *before* your angular reference

```
   <script src="/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If Angular sees JQuery while it's loading, `element` will be a full JQuery object, otherwise it's jqLite.

Comment: But when I refresh the page, it works good at the beginning. After a min or less it starting to fail.

Comment: I guess I'd need to see the code/fiddle then. It may be something you're doing with the directive or the DOM element it's bound to.

Comment: I have even tried adding .delay(2000), but still the same problem

Comment: I can try to make a fiddle, but It will be hard. Because its a project on local client connected to remote node server

Comment: @blesh, why do you think jQuery is needed?  addClass() and removeClass() are part of [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element), or are you thinking of something else?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a couple things:

#### 1. You are using `setTimeout` instead of `$timeout`.

When you do this you are executing your code outside of the Angular context so it doesn't know to do a dirty check. Try replacing

```
setTimeout(function(){
   element.removeClass(val);
 }, 2000);
```

with

```
$timeout(function(){
     element.removeClass(val);
}, 2000);
```

You'll also need to include `$timeout` as an argument to the directive factory method.

#### 2. You're using `scope.$watch` instead of `attrs.$observe`

I'm not sure about the ramifications here but this is how I've always seen it done before.

try:

```
attrs.$observe('myDirective', function(val){
 ...
}
```